# Incompatible types error in ArrayList<Object>

Tags: java, android, arraylist, casting, android-recyclerview

I am trying to put ads in a RecyclerView which is currently parsing a JSON file, the problem is that the ArrayList is throwing a casting error when I try to fill it with ads or the data from JSON.

Errors occur at two places, one in the `RecyclerViewAdapter()` method body and other one in the `BindViewHolder()`.

Here is my code from RecyclerViewAdapter.java (Error commented in 5th line)

```
private ArrayList<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CardSetterGetter> arrayList, ArrayList<String> favouriteItemList, int totalCount) {
    this.context = context;
    this.arrayList = arrayList; //Incompatible types.  Required: ArrayList<java.lang.object>;    found: ArrayList<com.comp.app.modal.CardSetterGetter>
    this.favouriteItemList = favouriteItemList;
    this.totalCount = totalCount;

}
```

`onBindViewHolder()` (Error commented in 27th line)

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    int viewType = getItemViewType(position);

    switch (viewType){

        case AD_VIEW_TYPE:
            NativeExpressAdViewHolder nativeExpressHolder = (NativeExpressAdViewHolder)holder;
            NativeExpressAdView adView = (NativeExpressAdView)arrayList.get(position);

            ViewGroup adCardView = (ViewGroup)nativeExpressHolder.itemView;
            adCardView.removeAllViews();

            if(adView.getParent() != null){
                ((ViewGroup)adView.getParent()).removeView(adView);
            }

            adCardView.addView(adView);
            break;

        case MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:

        default:
            String card_image;
            CardSetterGetter cardSetterGetter;
            cardSetterGetter = arrayList.get(position); //Incompatible types.  Required: ArrayList<com.comp.app.modal.CardSetterGetter>;    found: ArrayList<java.lang.object>;

            card_image = constants.SERVERIP.concat(cardSetterGetter.getImageurl());
            holder.cardSetterGetter = cardSetterGetter;
            holder.title.setText(cardSetterGetter.getImagetitle()); //set title

            PointF focusPoint = new PointF(0.5f, 0f);
            // your app populates the focus point

            holder.image // set image
                    .getHierarchy()
                    .setActualImageFocusPoint(focusPoint);
            holder.image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(card_image));
    }

}
```

Here is my CardSetterGetter.java

```
public class CardSetterGetter implements Serializable {
    private  String  imagetitle ;
    private  String  imageurl;
    private  String  description;
    private  String  tag;
    private  boolean isFavorite;

    public String getImageId() {
        return imageId;
    }

    public void setImageId(String imageId) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }

    public String getFavourite() {
        return favourite;
    }

    public void setFavourite(String favourite) {
        this.favourite = favourite;
    }

    private  String  imageId ;
    private  String favourite ;



    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public  String category;

    public CardSetterGetter(){

    }

    public String getImagetitle() {
        return imagetitle;
    }

    public void setImagetitle(String imagetitle) {
        this.imagetitle = imagetitle;
    }

    public String getImageurl() {
        return imageurl;
    }

    public void setImageurl(String imageurl) {
        this.imageurl = imageurl;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public void setTag(String tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public CardSetterGetter(String imageurl , String imagetitle , String description , String category , String tag,String imageId ,String favourite){
        this.imageurl = imageurl ;
        this.imagetitle = imagetitle ;
        this.description = description ;
        this.tag = tag ;
        this.category = category ;
        this.isFavorite =false ;
        this.imageId = imageId ;
        this.favourite = favourite ;
    }


    public boolean isFavorite() {
        return isFavorite;
    }

    public void setFavorite(String favorite) {
        favourite = favorite;
    }
}
```

I tried some of the questions on StackOverFlow like this one ([Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)), but I am unable to understand the basic concept of the solution, I already changed the datatype to Object (from CardSetterGetter).

Also tell me what happens if this issue of casting is solved and the arrayList returns adView where CardSetterGetter is expected or vice-versa, Do I need to put all such statements in try catch blocks?

Comment: can you post your `CardSetterGetter` class

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh Sure, I made some edits.

Comment: so if you are passing a `ArrayList<CardSetterGetter>` list then how it can have `NativeExpressAdView` objects?, we need to know from where `NativeExpressAdView` is coming from

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh I was following the official tutorial by google tutorial to ad NativeExpressAdView in RecyclerView. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LZCZSeFTvyk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue : your List is containing two kind of items `CardSetterGetter` and  `NativeExpressAdView` hence you need to use List of `Objects` instead of any specific type because both types has no relation plus apply the casting at appropriate places

use this

```
public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Object> arrayList, ArrayList<String> favouriteItemList, int totalCount) {
```

and use casting

```
cardSetterGetter =(CardSetterGetter ) arrayList.get(position);
```

instead of

```
public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CardSetterGetter> arrayList, ArrayList<String> favouriteItemList, int totalCount) {
```

> Also tell me what happens if this issue of casting is solved and the
>   arrayList returns adView where CardSetterGetter is expected or
>   vice-versa, Do I need to put all such statements in try catch blocks?

`getItemViewType(position)` is working as per `position`

```
   // ITEMS_PER_AD = 8
   return (position % MainActivity.ITEMS_PER_AD == 0) ? NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_VIEW_TYPE
                : MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE;
```

mean result of `position % 8 == 0` item (0,8,16,24,32...) in your list will be of `NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_VIEW_TYPE` type so it's `position` dependent math.

Comment: That solves the issue but now I am getting the casting error in the fragment where i am using this adapter. An object is expected but CardSetterGetter is found

Comment: @Ishanhrx you know as per this logic , you can only add adtype object to your list to position , where position % 8 ==0  so if you break this rule , you will get exceptions

Comment: So i call this method in an if else block?

Comment: @Ishanhrx see the code you are following is having list like this `add,item,item,item,item,item,item,add,item,item...` notice positions%8==0 is always ads items ,so your project should follow this as well, if you didn't change anything in positioning then post your error details and related code in your post at the end

Comment: @Ishanhrx tip :  for safe casting you can use `instanceof`  like `if listitem instanceod AdView` then case to adview `else` cast to your CardSetterGetter type

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your member definition:

```
private ArrayList<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

It probably should be:

```
private ArrayList<CardSetterGetter> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

The issue here is that `ArrayList<CardSetterGetter>` is not assignable to `ArrayList<Object>` - although `CardSetterGetter` (and all objects) are assignable to `Object`.

Comment: That removes the current errors but create a similar (casting) error in 10th line of `onBindViewHolder()`, where we are trying to get adView from this arrayList.

Answer (score 0):

change arraylist initialization like this

```
private ArrayList<CardSetterGetter> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: That removes the current errors but create a similar (casting) error in 10th line of `onBindViewHolder()`, where we are trying to get adView from this arrayList.

Comment: there also you will have to change the model type to CardSetterGetter

Comment: can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: i can tell that if i know what are you trying to acheive here, your arraylist here cannot be cast to NativeExpressAdView as it is of type CardSetterGetter

Comment: if you just want to get your arraylist by position just do like this 
    CardSetterGetter cardSetterGetter;
    cardSetterGetter = arrayList.get(position);

Comment: That is exactly what i did.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `ArrayList<Object> arrayList` in your RecyclerViewAdapter.java

`private ArrayList<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();`

to

`private ArrayList<CardSetterGetter> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();`

this will solve your problem

Comment: That removes the current errors but create a similar (casting) error in 10th line of `onBindViewHolder()`, where we are trying to get adView from this arrayList.

Comment: let me check why this is happening