# Incompatible types. Found: 'java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Object>', required: 'java.util.ArrayList<UserLocation>'

Tags: arrays, arraylist

So I am creating a route planner app in Android Studio and its giving me the error in the title of this question
Heres my code

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.destinationrouteplanner.R;
import com.example.destinationrouteplanner.adapters.UserRecyclerAdapter;
import com.example.destinationrouteplanner.models.MarkerCluster;
import com.example.destinationrouteplanner.models.User;
import com.example.destinationrouteplanner.util.MyClusterManagerRenderer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.maps.android.clustering.ClusterManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UserListFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback
{
    private static final String TAG = "UserListFragment";

    private RecyclerView mUserListRecyclerView;

    private MapView mMapView;

    private ArrayList<User> mUserList = new ArrayList<>();

    //private UserRecyclerAdapter mUserRecyclerAdapter;
    private ArrayList<UserLocation> mUserLocations = new ArrayList<>();
    private UserRecyclerAdapter mUserRecyclerAdapter;
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private LatLngBounds mMapBoundary;
    private UserLocation mUserPosition;
    private ClusterManager mClusterManager;
    private MyClusterManagerRenderer mClusterManagerRenderer;
    private ArrayList<MarkerCluster> mClusterMarkers = new ArrayList<>();


    public static UserListFragment newInstance() {
        return new UserListFragment();
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mUserList = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList(getString(R.string.intent_user_list));
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_list, container, false);
        mUserListRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.user_list_recycler_view);
        mMapView = view.findViewById(R.id.user_list_map);

        initUserListRecyclerView();
        initGoogleMap(savedInstanceState);

        return view;
    }

    private void initGoogleMap(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        // *** IMPORTANT ***
        // MapView requires that the Bundle you pass contain _ONLY_ MapView SDK
        // objects or sub-Bundles.
        Bundle mapViewBundle = null;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mapViewBundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
        }

        mMapView.onCreate(mapViewBundle);

        mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    private void initUserListRecyclerView() {
        mUserRecyclerAdapter = new UserRecyclerAdapter(mUserList);
        mUserListRecyclerView.setAdapter(mUserRecyclerAdapter);
        mUserListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        Bundle mapViewBundle = outState.getBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
        if (mapViewBundle == null) {
            mapViewBundle = new Bundle();
            outState.putBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY, mapViewBundle);
        }

        mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(mapViewBundle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mMapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mMapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mGoogleMap = map;
        addMapMarkers();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        mMapView.onPause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mMapView.onDestroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    private void addMapMarkers()
    {
        if (mGoogleMap !=null)
        {
            if(mClusterManager == null)
            {
                mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MarkerCluster>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), mGoogleMap);
            }
            if (mClusterManagerRenderer == null)
            {
                mClusterManagerRenderer = new MyClusterManagerRenderer(getActivity(), mGoogleMap, mClusterManager);
                mClusterManager.setRenderer(mClusterManagerRenderer);
            }
            for (UserLocation userLocation: mUserLocations)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "AddMapMarkers: location: " + userLocation.getGeo_point().toString());
                try {
                    String snippet = "";
                    if (userLocation.getUser().getUser_id().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()))
                    {
                        snippet = "This is you";
                    }else {
                        snippet = "Determine route to " + userLocation.getUser().getUsername() + "?";
                    }
                    int avatar = R.drawable.cwm_logo; //Set the default avatar
                    try {
                        avatar = Integer.parseInt(userLocation.getUser().getAvatar());
                    }catch (NumberFormatException e)
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "addMapMarkers: no avatar for: " + userLocation.getUser().getUsername() + ", setting default");
                    }
                    MarkerCluster newMarkerCluster = new MarkerCluster(new LatLng(userLocation.getGeo_point().getLatitude(), userLocation.getGeo_point().getLongitude(), userLocation.getUser().getUsername(), snippet, avatar, userLocation.getUser()));
                    mClusterManager.addItem(newMarkerCluster);
                    mClusterMarkers.add(newMarkerCluster);
                }catch (NullPointerException e)
                {
                    Log.e(TAG "addMapMarkers: NullPointerException: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            mClusterManager.cluster();
            setCameraView();
        }
    }
    private void setCameraView()
    {
        double bottomBoundary = mUserPosition.getGeo_point().getLatitude() - .1;
        double leftBoundary = mUserPosition.getGeo_point().getLongitude() - .1;
        double topBoundary = mUserPosition.getGeo_point().getLatitude() - .1;
        double rightBoundary = mUserPosition.getGeo_point().getLongitude() - .1;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {

    }
}
```

I tired using the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46490075/incompatible-types-error-in-arraylistobject) but not working
Required type:
ArrayList

Provided:
ArrayList

no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that UserLocation conforms to Object